# Mule-SAP Connector Error Message "Please enter sold-to party or ship-to party"

Tags: mule, sap-erp, saprfc

I am using Mule-SAP Connector(v)3.5.0 to Create Sales Order.

I see following error message in `RETURN`:

- Row 0

  > ```
  > Type: E
  > ID: VP
  > Message: Please enter sold-to party or ship-to party
  > ```
- Row 1

  > ```
  > Type: E
  > ID: V4
  > Message: Sales document was not changed
  > ```

Mapping Details

[image]

Code Snippet:

```
<sap:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"
        type="function" functionName="BAPI_SALESORDER_CREATEFROMDAT2"
        xmlVersion="2" outputXml="true" responseTimeout="10000"
        connector-ref="sap-connector" doc:name="create-sales-order">
        <sap:definition><![CDATA[
         <jco>
                <import>
                <structure name="ORDER_HEADER_IN">
                     <field name="DOC_TYPE">ZBV1</field>
                     <field name="SALES_ORG">1000</field>
                     <field name="DISTR_CHAN">6</field>
                     <field name="DIVISION">1</field>
                     <field name="SALES_OFF">MCT</field>
                     <field name="SALES_GRP">2</field>
                </structure>
                </import>
                
                <tables>
                    
                    <table name="ORDER_PARTNERS">
                       <row id="0">
                          <field name="PARTN_ROLE">PE</field>//Customer sold to party 
                          <field name="PARTN_NUMB">4275</field>
                         </row> 
                        <row id="1">
                          <field name="PARTN_ROLE">SP</field> //Employee sold to party
                          <field name="PARTN_NUMB">60001039</field>
                      </row> 
                    </table>
                    
                    
                    
                    
                    
                    <table name="ORDER_SCHEDULES_IN">
                      <row id="0">
                        <field name="REQ_QTY">1</field>
                      </row>
                    </table>
                    <table name="ORDER_ITEMS_IN">
                      <row id="0">
                        <field name="MATERIAL">11753</field>
                        <field name="SALES_UNIT">EA</field>
                        <field name="PLANT">D006</field>
                        <field name="BATCH">384</field>
                      </row>
                    </table>
                </tables>
                
                
            </jco>]]></sap:definition>
    </sap:outbound-endpoint>
```

By the error message i insist that sold-to party is not correctly mapped.
So can any one please help me,  how do i map **sold-to party** and where am going wrong.

Many Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

Try with 'AG' instead of 'SP'. I faced the same problem which resolved by putting AG as PARTN_ROLE.